# Error in Coloring Datagridview Row in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a datageidview which supposed to color the rows with contains specific value

```
    private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow myrow in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                    if (myrow.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "Error")
                    {
                        myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else if (myrow.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "NoError")
                    {
                        myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

but i have a problem when the first row contains this value all the rows is colored with it's color

any help ??

Comment: it suppose to set the row in red if the value of cell 7 is Error
and i am using this code in datagridview_cellformating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CellFormatting event is sent for all visible cells in the grid. You may have better luck using the data given in the event to change the color.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        if (dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "Error")
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "NoError")
        {
             e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Nice but i want to color the whole row no the cell any changes in the code ??